# Array assembly and StaticArrays under Julia: Why is my performance so bad?

Tags: arrays, julia

I need to prepare "flattened" versions of 2D fftfrequencies in the shape Nx^2 * 2. Those are basically constructed like a ravel(meshgrid(fftfreqs1d,fftfreqs1d)) in matlab or python.

This appears to be no big deal in python, but can hang for reasonable array sizes in julia, especially when i want to build a StaticArray out of the intermediate results. To make it more confusing, @btime pretends that my arrays are created in no time, while they are clearly not.
My question is why this happens and how it is done right.

**I am aware that using julia it might be a waste to keep the full 2D fftfreqs in memory instead of using the 1D versions and a loop, but let us assume for a moment that i need it this way.**

Julia

```
function my_freqs1(Nnu::Int,T)
    dx = 2. /Nnu
    freq1d = fftfreq(Nnu).*dx
    nu = hcat(  vec([ i for i in freq1d, j in freq1d  ]),
                                    vec([ j for i in freq1d, j in freq1d  ]))
    return nu
end;
@btime my_freqs1(100,Float64)

28.528 μs (10 allocations: 312.80 KiB)
```

Julia, converting to a static array (in the hope for better performance of other code later on)

```
function my_freqs2(Nnu::Int,T)
    ### the same as above ###
    return SMatrix{Nnu^2,2,T}(nu)
end;
@btime my_freqs2(100,Float64)

94.540 μs (36 allocations: 470.38 KiB)
```

Python

```
def my_fftfreqs(xy):
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(np.shape(xy)[0],d=xy[1]-xy[0])
    fx,fy = np.meshgrid(freqs,freqs,indexing="ij")
    freq_list = np.transpose(np.asarray( [np.ravel(fx),np.ravel(fy)] ))
    return freq_list
%time f=my_fftfreqs(np.linspace(0,1,100));

CPU times: user 1.08 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.08 ms
Wall time: 600 µs
```

My observation is that while python %time reports a much longer time, it will actually run in a very reasonable time while the julia version has a noticable delay and the version with the static array will hang for a long time and completely crash for larger sizes.

Please help me to understand how i would do this correctly in Julia and whether (why not?) creating a static array seems to be such a bad idea.

Comment: your additional line just builds a complex data structure and copies the data to it - how do you expect a performance gain here? On top of that `StaticArrays` are rather for arrays of 20 or 50 elements rather than several thousands

Comment: `SMatrix` is only for small (up to 10x10) matrices, and the size should be a compile-time constant, not a runtime value. That is the whole premise for their performance. For huge arrays you will have insane compile time, and no performance gain.

Comment: Przemyslaw Szufel, i did not expect experience gain at that point, but hoped for it when using the data later on. But i kind of suspected that there is a problem with using Staticarray for large arrays and that is affirmed by the answers here. So probably it is simply not the right choice here at all or the "long array  axis" could be turned into a standard Vector as suggested in the answer by Oscar Smith.

Comment: @WaveandMatter Are you *really, really* sure you need to store all those frequencies? It just seems so *horribly* wasteful, and counter to the general Julia philosophy of using smart, lightweight data structures instead of storing heavy, redundant data. Did you know that the `Frequencies` object returned by `fftfreq` is just a range object that takes up virtually no space, regardless of length? What are you using this for?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than making a `SMatrix{Nnu^2,2}` I think you probably want to make a `Vector{SVector{2}}`. The former will require recompiling for each new value of `Nnu` which is fairly inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider:

```
using FFTW

my_freqs3(ν) = fftfreq(ν)*2/ν |> 
  (w -> [repeat(w, inner=length(w)) repeat(w, outer=length(w))])

# or

my_freqs3alt(ν) = ( w = fftfreq(ν)*2/ν ; 
  [repeat(w, inner=length(w)) repeat(w, outer=length(w))] )
```

which is more Julian and "if-I-understand-correctly" is equivalent.

Usually shorter/simpler functions are also more efficient.

Julia features used:

- Unicode nu variable.
- Piping `|>` operator.
- Definition with no `function` keyword.
- `repeat` standard library vector filling function.
- Matlab-like `hcat` `[v1 v2]` notation.
- Multi-statement block enclosed in `( )` separated by `;`.